# Websockets transfer finished

Tags: javascript, websocket, socket.io, transfer

I'm using socket.io, and I would like to know when a send() command finished.
 - is it possible? 
 - is it possible in websockets?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can know, is by providing a callback when you send a message.
This invokes an ACK from the server.